# functional component to class component in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-functional-component

is it right or wrong please help

This is my functional component code

```
 setaddCategories((prevState) => {
      return [...prevState, { category_name: "", expense_categories_id: 0 }];
    });
```

and here I turn it into class component

```
    this.setState({
      addCategories: (prevState) => {
        return [...prevState, { category_name: "", expense_categories_id: 0 }];
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to get this **(Updated)**

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  addCategories: {
     ...prevState.addCategories,
     category_name: "",
     expense_categories_id: 0
  }
}));
```

Comment: sorry but its not working this error is showing - Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.

Comment: @HandCode Check my updated answer